# How to set logstash configuration output to use both HTTP & other HTTPS endpoints?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to send data to 2 endpoint from logstash, one of which is HTTP endpoint & other is HTTPS.

I tried putting username & password for HTTPS endpoint in url itself but logstash is taking those fields [username & password] for the other endpoint also.

my current output field if like:

```
output {
    elasticsearch{
        index => "index_name"
        document_id => "%{index_id}"
        hosts => ["https://elastic:pass@clusterid.asia-northeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243",
                  "http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
                }
      }
```

Getting this message in logs:

```
Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[https://elastic:xxxxxx@clusterid.asia-northeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/, https://elastic:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1:9200/]}}
```

And this:

```
[logstash.agent] Failed to execute action {:id=>:"cloud-elastic", :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<cloud-elastic>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

Comment: If you want to send the same data to two different elasticsearch clusters, you'll have to use two distinct elasticsearch outputs. Multiple hosts in the `hosts` params will just be used for load balancing (`If given an array it will load balance requests across the hosts specified in the hosts parameter.` from the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please try using different elasticsearch output for https and http,below settings

```
if "Https" in [tag]{
    elasticsearch {
                hosts => [ "https://elastic:pass@clusterid.asia-northeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243" ]
                user => "${ES_USER:admin}"
                password => "${ES_PWD:admin}"
                ssl => true
                ssl_certificate_verification => false
                cacert => "${CERTS_DIR}/certs/ca.crt"
                index => "%{[docInfo][index]}"
                action => "index"
              }
            } else {
               elasticsearch {
                hosts => [ "http://127.0.0.1:9200" ]
                index => "%{[docInfo][index]}"
                action => "index"
              }
}
```

In .bashrc file

set the below environment variables

```
export ES_USER=elastic
export ES_PWD=pass
export CERTS_DIR=/home/abc
```